# "Resubscribe not available" warning message in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, billing

I had been using the AIDL IabHelper classes for billing subscriptions in my app for years. Now, even though I have implemented the Google Play Billing Library 3.0 in the production .apk, I am still getting this warning in the Google Play Console. Any suggestions?

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0'
```

> Resubscribe is not currently available for your users because your app
> does not use Billing Library 2.0 in all active APKs.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @mgonzalez No, I still got this message

Comment: same here.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: not me.. I am still getting this message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my issue.

I had a version that included a "Retained app bundle and APK" in both Production and Open Testing channels (see screenshot)

[image: retained apk in google play with version 4.0.76]
Version 4.0.76 was including an older version of Google Play Billing Library and this was the reason why I had the error.

The steps for me were:

1. Prepare a new version in Open Testing
2. Remove the "retained apk" from the three dots menu.
3. Publish the version
4. Repeat same steps for Production
5. Once the versions were published, the error dissapeared.

This is how my version looks now:

[image]

Comment: This helped a lot. I had forgotten that I had created a Testing apk, 2 years ago, that contained an older version of the Billing Library. So now I simply uploaded a new version of the apk in the Open Testing and the error message disappeared.